# Why isn't my jQuery that I've embedded in my PHP executing properly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
if ($_POST["name"] == "") { 
    array_push($errors, "Your PixelPal needs a name!");
    echo "<script>\$('#name').css({ 'border': 'none', 'box-shadow': 'inset 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)' });</script>";
}
```

Basically, if the name variable isn't set I want it to echo a script that will change it to be highlighted in red. Why won't this work?

Here's it formatted nicer for reading:

```
if ($_POST["name"] == "") { 
    array_push($errors, "Your PixelPal needs a name!");
    echo "<script>\$('#name').css({
        'border': 'none',
        'box-shadow': 'inset 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
     });</script>";
}
```

Shouldn't JavaScript execute right away if pushed to the page?

Comment: Why are you doing this with JavaScript anyway? You're just setting CSS based on server-side variables. Just check these when you create those HTML elements and add the CSS inline there.

Comment: Where in the page have you echoed this? It may be running before the document has loaded

Comment: @AgentConundrum I don't follow. Could you be more clear?

Comment: @DougSmith Sure. The only thing the javascript you're adding is doing is adding CSS styles to certain elements. Rather than doing it in JavaScript, just do it by adding a `style` attribute to the element when you create the HTML. For example, try `echo "<div id='name' " . (!$_POST['name'] ? "style='border: none; ...' " : "") . " />";`

Answer (score 1):

JQuery script acts over elements that are already on the page, if you are executing this script before the element `id="name"`, you need to add the script inside a `$(document).ready` statement.

```
if ($_POST["name"] == "") { 
    array_push($errors, "Your PixelPal needs a name!");
    echo "<script>
\$(document).ready({
\$('#name').css({
        'border': 'none',
        'box-shadow': 'inset 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
     });
 });</script>";
}
```